# IBMi: 'Maximum numbe of uses' attribute of QZDASOINIT job indicates SQL requests or transactions?

Tags: ibm-midrange

On IBMi systems, the database server job - QZDASOINIT - has an attribute 'Maximum number of uses' which means that one QZDASOINIT job will accept the configured number of SQL requests before ending. The default value is 200. But, is a transaction with multiple SQL statements considered as a single request? If not, what will happen if a transaction consists of more than 200 SQL statements?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nothing.

Uses in this case is connections.

- Connect
- do stuff
- disconnect

Is one use, doesn't matter if do stuff consists on one SQL statement or 10,000.

- connect
- do stuff
- disconnect

Now, we've had two uses.

Note: if you're using connection pooling....the application can disconnect, returning the connection to the pool, without the connection actually being closed.  Thus the i will continue to see it as the initial connection.